# different rendering of letter spacing chrome vs firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I have a html element that has letter-spacing:0.09em. I noticed that this element renders differently on firefox and chrome. I have read several articles and questions at SO, that this is because browsers render fonts differently, but in my case i think the difference between this browsers is too big

[on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUifs.jpg)

[on firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcUq5.jpg)

i have tried using px too, but it is also renders differently. Is there any way to resolve this? or at least make the gap difference not as big as now.

thanks

updated css snippets:

```
#redband .btn.btn-default {
font-family: 'TR-MPZBASICHEAD-Bold', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 17px;
letter-spacing: 0.09em;
color: #DE3443;
border-radius: 0;
float: right;
height: 34px;
line-height: 35px;
margin-top: 30px;
border-color: #fff;
padding: 0 30px;
}
```

yes, i also use bootsrap. I wonder if bootstrap cause this (most likely not)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)